# Problems with jQuery .not() and the draggable ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Okay, when something is draggable, it is given the class .ui-draggable
And when something is disabled from being draggable .ui-draggable-disabled

I want to select only items that are draggable.

I'm using the following selector, but it doesn't seem to work. My disabled draggable items are still doing something on hover. Any ideas why?

```
$('.ui-draggable').not('.ui-draggable-disabled').hover(function() {
// rest of code
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
// selector means "doesn't have", ':not(:has(selector))'
$(".ui-draggable:not(:has(.ui-draggable-disabled))").hover(function() { ...
```

or:

```
$('.ui-draggable').not(':has(.ui-draggable-disabled)').hover(function() {
```

or test for the presence of the disabled class within the `hover` mouseover/mouseout functions:

```
$(".ui-draggable").hover(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("ui-draggable-disabled")) {
        // do stuff
    }
}, function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("ui-draggable-disabled")) {
        // do stuff
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would do the trick. Alas it doesn't. Weird.

Comment: No. It's a bit strange. I've tried removing the class too (in the same function that disables the draggable function), but jQuery still seems think the class still exists, and consequently does stuff on hover.

Comment: I tell a lie. The if statement works. There was an erroneous period in your code though.

Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.